# Salesforce1 scripts problem lightning

Tags: javascript, angular, tag

So I have implemented a script that uses angular as well, however when I use {{1+1}} it does nothing, also it shows me a warning that is created inside the Javascript file(we created it too show that it works).

The code for the lightning static resource is:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<ltng:require
              styles="/resource/bootstrap"
              scripts="/resource/BookingWidget"
    />

<html ng-app="">
    <body >
    {{1+1}}


    </body>
</html>
```

ng-app="" even being empty it should run {{1+1}}

I left it for five minutes and it gave me a warning

"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once"

Comment: Your opening `<html>` tag needs a closing pointed bracket - `<html ng-app="">`.  If it is closed in your code, please update this excerpt.

Comment: Yes it is closed in the code, my bad sorry.

Comment: Does the dev console display any errors?

Comment: No the Dev console doesn't display any errors